# How to put translatable text (including English) into files in Django

Tags: django, localization

I'd like to have all of my templates' actual non-html text in one (or multiple) seperate files in Django. At the moment my templates are quite jam-packed by passages like:

```
{% if request.session.lang == "en" %}
    Some text in English
{% else %}
    Some text in the default language
{% endif %}
```

The templates' text (main language or English) gets changed often by other people, so I would like to just have some files, which other people can edit as well (without having to edit the actual view-files).
After reading the localization section of django docs, it seems that one still has to hardcode text (English in the docs' examples) into the templates/views.

Example from django docs on generated .po files:

```
msgid "Welcome to my site."
msgstr ""
```

I'd rather have something like:

```
msgid APP-XY_VIEW-XY_INTRODUCTION
msgstr ""
```

Of course, the obvious solution seems like using something like:

```
ugettext('APP-XY_VIEW-XY_INTRODUCTION') # in a view
```

However, I'd like to make sure if there's no other solution (without creating some custom id string literals, that are hardcoded in every view/template).

Thanks very much!

/edit, Django Version 1.4.5

Comment: {% trans APP-XY_VIEW-XY_INTRODUCTION %}  doesnt help ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear bout this. My problem is that I'd rather avoid cooking up some custom IDs like in the example (APP-XY_VIEW-XY_INTRODUCTION). I edited the opening post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Django you are using (you should pretty much always include this information - it will help you get the best answers).  But, you should just be able to put

```
{% load i18n %}
```

at the top of your template.  Then you can just call trans and handle it like you would your models, etc.

```
<title>{% trans "My very important title" %}</title>
```

The Django book 2.0 has a pretty good chapter on this topic.  Might be work a read?  Click [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19.html) for more info.

Comment: The point is, that I don't want to hardcode "My very important title" into any python files or django templates. The page's default language, as well as others, should ALL be in their seperate seperate files (like django messagefiles) so that other people can edit them. In the django docs it's assumed that one wants to hardcode text of the main language right into the templates/views. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create language files for the same language as your project and it will override the hardcoded strings (both template and views)

my project:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
```

In `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` my translators can override my faulty/bad choice of words